# Is there a different way to update the wrapper for when dynamically updating dropdown checklst

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to create a html and java script front-end for my python back-end. I am parsing the data from a tsv file and then dynamically updating the drop down list. I don't have much experience with html and javascript and am trying to learn.

I am using jQuery drop down multiselect

```
 <form id="form-user" action="#" method="post">
  <center>
    <select id='testSelect1' multiple>
      <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
      <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
      <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
      <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
      <option value='5'>Item 5</option>
      <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
      <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
    </select>
  </center>
</form>
```

Code for html layout

```
$('#testSelect1').multiselect({
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'Select Shoporder',
    selectAll: true,
    minCount: 30
});
```

This is how I am initializing it:

```
function updateShopOrder(data) {
   var inner_HTML = [];
   var temp = "<option value=";
   const element = document.getElementById('testSelect1');
   var value = "hello";

   $(document).ready(function() {
       for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            //var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            //newOption.value = "tt";
            //newOption.text = "test";
            //element.add(newOption);
            element.innerHTML += temp.concat(i.toString(), ">", "item ", i.toString(), "</option>");
            //document.multiselect('#testSelect1').append("<option value=\"" + i.toString() + "\">" + value 
            + " </option>");
            //$('#testSelect1').multiselect( 'refresh' );
            //$('#testSelect1').multiselect( 'rebuild' );
       }
    });
}
```

Code for how i am trying to update the the list. Commented out are stack overflow solutions I tried before. However everything I tried so far updates the html but does not update the wrapper (observation from devtools) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXKqd.png).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// DYNAMICALLY LOAD OPTIONS
$('select[multiple]').multiselect( 'loadOptions', [{
    name   : 'Option Name 1',
    value  : 'option-value-1',
    checked: false,
    attributes : {
        custom1: 'value1',
        custom2: 'value2'
  }
},{
    name   : 'Option Name 2',
    value  : 'option-value-2',
    checked: false,
    attributes : {
       custom1: 'value1',
       custom2: 'value2'
}
```

}]);

I found this in the documentation but how would i go about implementing it using a for loop?

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap library for multiselect? with this method you don't really need it. You could change `document.multiselect('#testSelect1')` to just jquery `$('#testSelect1')`

Comment: I dont have the bootstrap library. I tried that too, this is just something else I was trying. I also added a screenshot for the devtool reference in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
// APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
$('#testSelect1').append('<option value="' + value.ID + '">' + value.Name + '</option>');
});
```

Iterate over your data somehow and append that to the html file. Refresh periodically for the change to reflect in your html

Comment: I am trying not to use anything other then jquery and javascript. As i dont when i try to package it with eel how much of a issue it would be. Also the client doesnot want the application using any online resources. I also added a screenshot for the devtool reference in case it helps.

Comment: Still the same issue. However I did found something that looks like a json list in the documentation. But how can i create something like that without a for loop. I couldnt post the code in the comment so i updated the post with what i am referring to.

Comment: I mean to say how can i generate a OPTGROUPS using for loop in javascript